# Footer not at bottom

Tags: css

There is a content class, in which there 2 have class classes in it, One is left float and other is right float as you seen in image.

I want a footer at the end or bottom of my page, i.e after the 2 classes div ends.

[image]

CSS:

```
.footer
{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%; 
    height:25px; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    margin-left:auto;
    color:white;
    bottom:0px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

But is it not working. If you see the image,it is not at the bottom... even though `bottom:0px`? Is there any problem?

Comment: First add Clear:Both; to your code. It will remove all the floats and your code will move down.

Comment: have you cleared the float after last floated element.? Here right sidebar is  the last element.

Comment: Sorry where should I add? I never used clear and I have no idea of it..

Comment: Position absolute will do that...I suspect you need a proper "sticky footer".

Comment: Can you provide site link?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes i want something like that,

Comment: Well now you know what to search for. Off you go. :) Here's a starter - http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: Yes! Clear worked, after removing absolute! Thanks @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before footer div

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

and remove `position: absolute` from footer css

Comment: Clearing the float won't affect an absolutely positioned footer.

Comment: Agree with @Paulie_D . No need of position absolute here.